# How to collect the id once I click on image linked update page in php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, crud

This is my whole html and php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Student Details</h2>
        <div id="EditStudent">
            <a href="UpdateStudent.php?SelectionId=$Carrier"><img src="sawiro/EditImage.jpg" alt="Edit Student Image"></a>
        </div>
        <table style="width: 100%" border ="0" bordercolor="green" bgcolor="white" cellspacing="20" cellpadding="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
        <?php
                $Carrier = 0;
                function clearInput($data){
                    $data = trim($data);
                    $data = stripslashes($data);
                    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                    return $data;
                        }
            if(isset($_GET['SelectedId'])){
                $Carrier = clearInput($_GET['SelectedId']);
                    }
                    $cnx = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=transportsystem;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
                    $result = $cnx->query("SELECT * FROM person
                                                    INNER JOIN student ON person.PerID = student.StPersonID
                                                    WHERE PerID = $Carrier");

                    while($row = $result->fetch()){
                    $Name = $row["Name"];
                    $Gender = $row["Gender"];
                    $Telephone = $row["Telephone"];
                    $Class = $row["Class"];
                        echo '<th colspan="8" style="font-size:40px;">'.$row["Name"].'</th>';
                    }

        ?>      
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <tr style="color: #000;">
                    <th> Student ID:</th>
                    <td><?php echo $Carrier;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> Full Name:</th>
                    <td><?php echo $Name;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> Gender:</th>
                    <td><?php echo $Gender;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> Telephone:</th>
                    <td><?php echo $Telephone;?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th> Class:</th>
                    <td><?php echo $Class;?></td>
                </tr>       

        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to add Selectionid, as you can see on it

```
?SelectionId=$Carrier;
```

where my id variable is `$Carrier` becuase of this code

```
if(isset($_GET['SelectedId']))
    {$Carrier = clearInput($_GET['SelectedId']);}
```

I want once I click on `<img src="sawiro/EditImage.jpg" alt="Edit Student Image">` to give me url `UpdateStudent.php?SelectionId=8` for example, to use this id for setting data purpose.

Please help me to collect the id from the target php to use in to another php to update that particular row.

Comment: Not sure what `?SelectionId='."$Carrier".';"` is suppose to do. If you want to add the ID to the string, you need to add a php block: `"UpdateStudent.php?SelectionId=<?= $Carrier ?>"` (this is PHP 101). If that's not the issue, you need to clarify your questions because it's _very_ unclear what you're actually asking.

Comment: Where will you get the `$_GET['SelectedId']`?

Comment: `$Carrier` will never have a value because `$_GET['SelectedId']` seems to be missing in your codes

Comment: It is not missing, you can see in the if statement

Comment: What I mean is that where will you get `$_GET['SelectedId']`? Without it, `$Carrier` will never have a value. I suggest you check the flow of your codes, and check for typos as well

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. htmlspecialchars and stripslashes are _not_ safe enough for escaping user inputs.

Comment: You should add `$Carrier` to the url in the way @Tesseract suggests in the answer below. Another thing, you're trying to add `$Carrier` to the url _before_ you set it so it will be undefined when you're trying to use it the first time. You should add display errors and check your error log. I bet you would get some warnings that might help you when you're debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant it like this:

```
<a href="UpdateStudent.php?SelectionId=<?php echo $Carrier ;?>">
    <img src="sawiro/EditImage.jpg" alt="Edit Student Image"/>
</a>
```

Comment: @MohamedAbdullahiSalah - You really need to start giving us more info if you want more help. What does _"not yet solved"_ mean? Any error messages? What happens? What's the expected outcome? Was it this solution that didn't work or is it something else?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - the outcome of your treatment was too long to post here, by the way, I want to collect the id from the target php to use in to another php to update that particular row.

Comment: @MohamedAbdullahiSalah It's simple, you should update the _question_ with more information about your issue, add all relevant code, rephrase the question itself to be more clear and give us more than "not working" on suggestions. The above code will pass the `SelectionId` to the next page, so if that doesn't work, then there are other things that doesn't work, which we _have no idea about_ since you won't clarify your issue. We can only do so much with the info you're giving us. Remember that we don't know your code or what it looks like.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - I have edited, please help me if you have an idea